# setState not working correctly. Filter checkboxes not being checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm learning to create a basic ecommerce site where you can search for shoes, and filter the results based on the brand and type of shoe.

My progress so far:

- Clicking on filter checkboxes populates the URL with the correct parameters
- Now, I'm trying to read the URL parameters and use it to check the checkbox filters. This is for the case where the user visits the URL of `http:www.website.com?brand=nike` and I'd like the search results page to have the "nike" checkbox checked, along with only results for nike

Problem:

- The URL parameters are being parsed correctly, however, the checkboxes are not being checked
- In fact, I can't even check the checkboxes in the UI at all unless I comment out the line `setSelectedFilters(newFilters)` from `parseQueryFilters`

Questions:

1. Why is there an issue with the setState `setSelectedFilters(newFilters)`? And why is it preventing the checkboxes from being checked? Does it have to do with the `useEffect` call?
2. Even if I can get the checkboxes to work, will calling that cause the checkboxes to be checked based on the parsed URL parameters?

```js
const filters = [
  {
    id: 'brand',
    name: 'Brand',
    options: [
      { value: 'nike', label: 'Nike', checked: false },
      { value: 'adidas', label: 'Adidas', checked: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'type',
    name: 'Type',
    options: [
      { value: 'basketball', label: 'Basketball', checked: false },
      { value: 'running', label: 'Running', checked: false },
      { value: 'training', label: 'Training', checked: false },
    ],
  },
];
```

```tsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSearchParams, usePathname, useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

export default function Filters() {
  const [selectedFilters, setSelectedFilters] = useState(filters);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { replace } = useRouter();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const buildQueryString = () => {
    // No longer needs the 'filters' argument
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    selectedFilters.forEach((filter) => {
      const selectedOptions = filter.options
        .filter((option) => option.checked)
        .map((option) => option.value);
      if (selectedOptions.length > 0) {
        params.append(filter.id, selectedOptions.join(','));
      }
    });
    return params.toString();
  };

  // Call on filter change for URL update:
  useEffect(() => {
    const queryString = buildQueryString();
    // router.push(`${pathname}?${queryString}`, undefined, { shallow: true });
    replace(`${pathname}?${queryString}`);
  }, [selectedFilters, router]);

  const updateFilters = (
    filterId: string,
    optionValue: string,
    checked: boolean,
  ) => {
    console.log(
      `updateFilters ---- filterId: ${filterId} || optionValue: ${optionValue} || checked: ${checked}`,
    );

    setSelectedFilters((prevFilters) => {
      return prevFilters.map((filter) => {
        if (filter.id === filterId) {
          filter.options = filter.options.map((option) => ({
            ...option,
            checked: option.value === optionValue ? checked : option.checked,
          }));
        }
        return filter;
      });
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const parseQueryFilters = () => {
      const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);

      console.log('Initial filters:', filters); // Log the original state
      console.log('Query Params:', queryParams);

      const newFilters = filters.map((filter) => ({
        ...filter,
        options: filter.options.map((option) => ({
          ...option,
          checked:
            queryParams.get(filter.id)?.split(',').includes(option.value) ??
            false,
        })),
      }));
      console.log('newFilters', newFilters);

      // Problem line below. Filter checkboxes can't be checked.
      // setSelectedFilters(newFilters);
    };

    parseQueryFilters();
  }, [router]);

  return (
    <div className="hidden md:block">
      {/* Filters */}
      <form>
        {filters.map((selectedFilters) => (
          <div
            key={selectedFilters.id}
            className="border-b border-slate-400 py-3"
          >
            <h3 className="font-medium text-gray-900">
              {selectedFilters.name}
            </h3>

            {selectedFilters.options.map((option) => (
              <div key={option.value} className="flex items-center">
                <input
                  id={`${selectedFilters.id}-${option.value}`}
                  value={option.value}
                  type="checkbox"
                  checked={option.checked}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    updateFilters(
                      selectedFilters.id,
                      option.value,
                      e.target.checked,
                    )
                  }
                  className="h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                />
                <label
                  htmlFor={`${selectedFilters.id}-${option.value}`}
                  className="ml-3 text-sm text-gray-600"
                >
                  {option.label}
                </label>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See above for what I've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are rendering the form with the constant `filters`, not with the state `selectedFilters`.

Comment: That worked! That fixed all the issues. I thought I replaced all the `filters` values in the form with `selectedFilters` but I missed the main one... thank you!

I can't upvote b/c I don't have enough reputation points, but thank you for catching that. Took me forever.

Comment: @ScoobaDiva you can mark as accepted though